# Are there theorems proved by showing the existence of some proof?

Tags: proof-theory, meta-math

While enjoying the reading of Nagel's book concerning Gödel's work, I asked myself various questions related to meta-mathematics. One of them is as follows:

*Are there examples of theorems which can be seen as proved in the following manner?*

- no "direct" or "explicit" proof is known;
- it can be proved that a proof *p* for this theorem should necessarily exist (it can't be that the proof *p* doesn't exist).

Of course the first requirement implies that the proof *p* by itself isn't known. I would be happy to have some examples in arithmetic if possible.

Comment: Actually, according to Löb's theorem, if proving that $p$ was provable is enough to establish $p$, then we could actually have proved $p$.

Comment: Suppose we have proved that a proof of a theorem must exist. How is this different from any non-constructive proof by contradiction? It isn't. We have just proved our theorem.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That's not really true in general. For example, the theory T="ZFC+"ZFC is inconsistent" proves "T proves 0=1," but by Godel's incompleteness theorem T doesn't actually prove 0=1 unless ZFC itself is inconsistent *(why? well, if T proved 0=1 then T would be inconsistent, and if a theory A+p is inconsistent then A proves not(p) - so this would mean that ZFC proves its own consistency)*. So we have to be careful here.